# Magento: Get Newsletter/Subscriber module to deliver email AND name to database

Tags: php, class, magento, methods, newsletter

Currently, it only grabs the email and delivers it to the database. I added the html for the name, but I needed to edit some other files for it to grab the info. I've done a ton of googling but I havent found any answer.

Comment: This will be a relatively involved task since the newsletter entity doesn't actually have fields for name. In the Adminhtml grid it only displays the fields for customers, and you can't create a customer from the newsletter signup as you don't have a password.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to develop your own extension.

First, you'll need somewhere in the database to put the name. You'll either need to alter the newsletter_subscriber table or create your own table. In either case, you need an install script.

Then you'll need to override the Mage_Newsletter_SubsscriberController newAction to store the information you want.

To do a complete job, you'll want to update the Admin interface (Adminhtml/Newsletter/Subscriber/Grid.php) and a few model files.